# Have trouble understanding capturing groups and back references

Tags: regex

Wishing to put some order into my knowledge of regular expressions I decided to go through a book about them, *Introducing Regular Expressions*. And I know it's silly but one of the introductory examples doesn't make sense to me.

```
(\d)\d\1
```

Sample text:

```
123-456-7890
```

(should capture the first number, `123`)

Can anyone explain what is going on in here?

As far as I can figure out, the first `\d` captures the number 123. The `\1` backreferences (marks) the group for later use. The parenthesis limit the scope of the group. But what does the second `\d` does?

Simple explanation, like to a small child or a golden retriever are prefered.

Comment: To truly grok regex, go read: [Mastering Regular Expressions (3rd Edition)](http://www.amazon.com/Mastering-Regular-Expressions-Jeffrey-Friedl/dp/0596528124 "By Jeffrey Friedl. Best book on Regex - ever!")

Comment: @ridgerunner - I think that one is a little too advanced for me at this stage. Maybe, in the days to come :)

Comment: Actually, MRE is written in a tutorial style and starts from the ground up starting with the very basics. Hands down, the most useful book I've ever read.

Comment: This question has been added to the [Stack Overflow Regular Expression FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22944075/2736496), under "Groups".

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`\d` is just **one** digit.

This regular expression doesn't match the `"123-456-7890"` string but it would match `"323"` (which could be part of a greater string, for example `"323-456-7890"`) :

```
 (\d) : first digit ("3")
 \d   : another digit ("2")
 \1   : first group (which was "3")
```

Now, if your book pretends that `(\d)\d\1` should capture `"123"` in `"123-456-7890"`, then it might contain an error...

Comment: If I understood you right. The first \d is just one digit (one character). In a parenthesis which represent a group. The second \d is just another digit. The \1 references to the last parenthesis, e.g. group no.1. Could I have just put \2, if I wanted to backreference it that way later on?

Comment: (\d) matched 3, \d matched 2, and \1 matched 3 again since that's what was matched / referenced from the first group?

Comment: @ldigas yes to all, apart I've not understood your question regarding \2.

Comment: Could I have named it ref. group "2" ... \2 instead of \1, or does \1 stand for 1st?

Comment: No : \1 is always the first one. The second group is named \2, etc.

Answer (score 10):

`(\d)\d\1` step by step:

1. The first `\d` matches one digit
2. And the parentheses `()` mark this as a capturing group - this is the first one, so the digit is remembered as "group 1"
3. The second `\d` says there is another digit
4. `\1` says "here is the value from our previous group 1" - that is the digit that was matched in step 1.

So like dystroy already said: the regex should match a sequence of three digits of which the first and the third are equal.