# Yahoo pipes : unlink text that target a specific domain

Tags: regex, pipe, yahoo, yahoo-pipes

i want to regex to remove any-link that start with example.com but i want to keep the text :

`<a rel="nofollow" target="_blank" href="http://example.com/somepage/">some text</a>`

I have tried a lot of regex with yahoo pipes and didn't work please help me guys.

Answer (score 0):

try this regex:

```
<a\s.+?example[.]com.+?>([^<]+)</a>
```

explain:

> ***`+?`***  Matches the previous element one or more times, but as few times as possible.
>
> ***`[^character_group]`*** Negation: Matches any single character that is not in `character_group`

Comment: workd but the text has been deleted i want to keep the text but temove the link

Comment: The text is in [capture group](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21880127) 1. Nothing else is captured. Use [`$1` or `\1`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21880127) to get it. For more information, see the section on "Groups" in the [Stack Overflow Regular Expressions FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22944075/2736496).

Answer (score 0):

user3526447, depending on context there may be a problem with the expression in the first answer, because from the initial "a" tag, the .+ will potentially run over multiple urls until it hits "example". 
This may not be a problem in the context you are using, if you are only working on single urls.

Instead, replace

```
(<a[^>]*?)example\.com
```

with $1 or \1