# Python regex to match groups of same length with match but varying between matches

Tags: python, regex

i would like to match the sequence `(G{x})([ACGT]{1,7})(G{x})([ACGT]{1,7})(G{x})([ACGT]{1,7})(G{x})` where x is a number between 2 and 5, which can vary between matches but must be the same between groups inside a single match. Is it possible to do this with a single regex?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [backreferencing](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21880127/7586):

```
(G{2,5})([ACGT]{1,7})\1([ACGT]{1,7})\1([ACGT]{1,7})\1
```

Working example: https://regex101.com/r/yL5tE6/1

Note that it does allow *more* `G`s than there were on the first group, because `[ACGT]` might add `G`s in adjacent to `\1`.