# Most efficient method to check for range of numbers within number without duplicates

Tags: javascript, algorithm, numbers

Given a number `n` , a minimum number `min` , a maximum number `max` , what is the most efficient method to determine

1. Number `n` is or is not within range , inclusive of , `min` - `max`
2. Number `n` does or does not contain duplicate numbers
3. Efficiency meaning here that the method or set of methods requires the least amount of computational resources and returns either `true` or `false` in the least amount of time
4. Context: Condition at `if` within a `for` loop which could require from thousands to hundreds of thousands of iterations to return a result; where milliseconds required to return `true` or `false` as to `Number` check could affect performance

At `Profiles` panel at `DevTools` on a collection of `71,3307` items iterated, `RegExp` below was listed as using `27.2ms` of total `1097.3ms` to complete loop . At a collection of `836,7628`  items iterated `RegExp` below used `193.5ms` within total of `11285.3ms` .

Requirement: Most efficient method to return `Boolean` `true` or `false` given above parameters , within the least amount of time.

Note: Solution does not have to be limited to `RegExp` ; used below as the pattern returned expected results.

---

Current `js` utilizing `RegExp` `re` , `RegExp.protype.test()`

```js
var min = 2
, max = 7
, re = new RegExp("[" + min + "-" + max + "](.)(?!=\1)", "g")
, arr = [81, 35, 22, 45, 49];

for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  console.log(re.test(arr[i]), i, arr[i])
    /*
      false 0 81 
      true 1 35
      false 2 22
      true 3 45
      false 4 49 
    */
}
```

Comment: You are given three nos ...right?

Comment: The regex is incorrect, you need to escape backslash. `new RegExp("[" + min + "-" + max + "](.)(?!=\\1)", "g")`

Comment: @MathewsMathai _"You are given three nos ...right?"_ The number could be between two numbers; e.g., `25` up to `n` numbers , e.g., nine numbers `271314892`

Comment: @Tushar _"The regex is incorrect, you need to escape backslash. `new RegExp("[" + min + "-" + max + "](.)(?!=\\1)", "g")`"_ Where `\1` is reference to capture group `(.)` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21880127/have-trouble-understanding-capturing-groups-and-back-references ?

Comment: @guest271314 Try `console.log(re);` and you'll see what I'm saying

Comment: So the basic purpose is to check if `n` is in between `min` and `max` or not?...Am I right??

Comment: @MathewsMathai _"So the basic purpose is to check if n is in between min and max or not?...Am I right?? "_ Given `271314892` `false` should be returned , as both a) duplicate `1` , and `2` , contains numbers outside of range `2` through `7`

Comment: @Tushar The `RegExp` is not ideal though has returned expected results . Can create jsfiddle to demonstrate different outcomes using `\1` , `\\1` as back reference ?

Comment: You can use `var range = new RegExp("^[" + min + "-" + max + "]+$"); if(range.test(number) === false) { return false; }` early return. and then only check for duplicates.

Comment: Check [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/dqcpn2h0/), you want to use back-reference, so need to escape slash.

Comment: @Tushar _"You can use var range = new RegExp("^[" + min + "-" + max + "]+$"); if(range.test(number) === false) { return false; "_ Can describe how approach would be different from, or more efficient than `RegExp` at Question ?

Comment: @Tushar Appear to return same result ? https://jsfiddle.net/dqcpn2h0/1/

Comment: @guest271314 If there are chances that the numbers to test are out of given range, this will check if the digits are in the range and if not, it'll early return so saving the next backreference regex(which is costly).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Associative arrays approach:

This has the advantage of being easily understandable.

```
function checkDigits(min, max, n) {
    var digits = Array(10);                   // Declare the length of the array (the 10 digits) to avoid any further memory allocation
    while (n) {
        d = (n % 10);                         // Get last digit
        n = n / 10 >>0;                       // Remove it from our number (the >>0 bit is equivalent to compose(Math.floor, Math.abs))
        if (d < min || d > max || digits[d])  // Test if "d" is outside the range or if it has been checked in the "digits" array
            return false;
        else
            digits[d] = true;                 // Mark the digit as existing
    }
}
```

```js
var min = 2
, max = 7
, arr = [81, 35, 22, 45, 49];

function checkDigits(min, max, n) {
    var digits = Array(10);                   // Declare the length of the array (the 10 digits) to avoid any further memory allocation
    while (n) {
        d = (n % 10);                         // Get last digit
        n = n / 10 >>0;                       // Remove it from our number (the >>0 bit is equivalent to compose(Math.floor, Math.abs))
        if (d < min || d > max || digits[d])  // Test if "d" is outside the range or if it has been checked in the "digits" array
            return false;
        else
            digits[d] = true;                 // Mark the digit as existing
    }
    return true;
}

for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  console.log(checkDigits(min, max, arr[i]), i, arr[i])
}
```

## Binary mask approach:

This replaces the Array with an integer that is in effect used as an array of bits. It should be faster.

```
function checkDigits(min, max, n) {
    var digits = 0;                   
    while (n) {
        d = (n % 10);                         
        n = n / 10 >>0;
        if (d < min || d > max || (digits & (1 << d)))
            return false;
        else
            digits |= 1 << d;
    }
    return true;
}
```

```js
function checkDigits(min, max, n) {
    var digits = 0;                   
    while (n) {
        d = (n % 10);                         
        n = n / 10 >>0;
        if (d < min || d > max || (digits & (1 << d)))
            return false;
        else
   digits |= 1 << d;
    }
    return true;
}
```

#### Explanation for binary mask approach:

`1 << d` creates a *bit mask*, an integer with the `d` bit set and all other bits set to 0.
`digits |= 1 << d` sets the bit marked by our bit mask on the integer `digits`.
`digits & (1 << d)` compares the bit marked by our bit mask with `digits`, the collection of previously marked bits.
See the docs on [bitwise operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators) if you want to understand this in detail.

So, if we were to check 626, our numbers would go like this:

```
________n_____626_______________
           |
        d  |  6
     mask  |  0001000000
   digits  |  0000000000
           |
________n_____62________________
           |
        d  |  2
     mask  |  0000000100
   digits  |  0001000000
           |
________n_____6_________________
           |
        d  |  6
     mask  |  0001000000
   digits  |  0001000100
                 ^
               bit was already set, return false
```

Comment: Can include comments at `js` describing approach ?

Comment: @guest271314 Done, feel free to ask if there's anything that remains unclear.

Comment: Why are five parameters passed where three parameters declared ?

Comment: Check the parentheses, 3 parameters are passed to `checkDigits`, the others are for `console.log`

Comment: Ahh. Nice . `4.0ms` for `713307 ` iterations

Comment: @guest271314 I added another solution, I'm curious to see the performance impact it'll have.

Comment: _"added another solution, I'm curious to see the performance impact it'll have. "_ Profiled loop three separate times with same 713307 iterations; results for second approach :  `1ms` , `2ms` , `1ms`

Comment: This appears to be a fine answer...I'll place my vote here based on the performance test done by the OP and your binary approach.....

Answer (score 0):

**Solution 1**

**test using regex**

```
var min = 2;
var max = 7;
res = "";
arr = [81, 35, 22, 45, 49]
arr.push("");
regex=new RegExp("[" + min + "-" + max + "](.)(?!=\1)", "g")
var result = arr.reduce(function(a, b) {
  if (regex.test(a)) {
    res = res + a + " is true\n"
  } else {
    res = res + a + " is false\n"
  };
  return b
});
console.log(res)
```

The reduce method is different in a sense that it is like a generator function like in python (produces output on the fly)

Its simply loops through each elements in an array using a callback function. I cannot say how efficient is the reduce function.

Nevertheless consider two elements in the array

```
81                             35          
^
take this value            take the result
and do something           from the previous 
                           element and add it
                           to the result computed
                           for this element
```

further information https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff679975%28v=vs.94%29.aspx

**SOlution 2**

Using list to store value and their boolean

```
var min = 2;
var max = 7;
res = [""];
arr = [81, 35, 22, 45, 49]
arr.push("");
regex=new RegExp("[" + min + "-" + max + "](.)(?!=\1)", "g")
var result = arr.reduce(function(a, b) {
  if (regex.test(a)) {
    res.push([a,true])
  } else {
    res.push([a,false])
  };
  return b
});
console.log(res)
```

Comment: `35` and `45` should return `true` ; `res` appear `undefined` ?

Comment: I use 2 and 7 for max value and I define var min=2 and var max =7..i make the edited

Comment: @reprezo Appear to return empty string from `.reduce()`  ? Expected return value is `Boolean` `true` or `false`

Comment: output is log in the console...it returns "" which is the last element in the array.. the output is also stored in the variable "res"..you can print this....ensure you reset the variable res to "" before rerunning the iterator method

Comment: change console.log(result) to console.log(res)

Comment: _"change console.log(result) to console.log(res)"_ `35` and `45` should return `true` https://jsfiddle.net/h4xs0gft/1/

Comment: all would be false since all values cannot be =>2 and <=7

Comment: _"all would be false since all values cannot be =>2 and <=7"_  ?`true` returned for all numbers at https://jsfiddle.net/repzeroworld/ztebfL8e/  . `81`, `22`  and `49` should return `false` ; see description of requirement at  Question

Comment: my apologies....I had to interchange "true" and "false" back in the string due to the logics........https://jsfiddle.net/repzeroworld/xjnk1jaq/

Comment: all values will be false.......unless you change your max to a higher number that a value in the array meets the condition

Comment: _"all values will be false.......unless you change your max to a higher number that a value in the array meets the condition"_  ? This is not correct. See text of Question at 1., 2. Each number appear returned as `false` at https://jsfiddle.net/repzeroworld/xjnk1jaq/ ?

Comment: Correct....81 is > 2 and not less than 7, 35 is > 2 and not less than 7,22 is > 22 and not less than 7 etc...all false

Comment: _"Correct....81 is > 2 and not less than 7, 35 is > 2 and not less than 7,81 is > 22 and not less than 7 etc...all false"_ No, not correct as to requirement of Question. E.g, `35` is actually two numbers

Comment: _"see edited answer"_  Can describe how updated solution is different from `js` at Question ? How would using `.reduce()` decrease time to return `true` or `false` using `.test()` . Why would `.reduce()` be necessary where `.test()` is used within callback of `.reduce()` ?

Comment: see edited answer as to how I understand the reduce function and from looking up the reference link

Comment: Requirement is to return `Boolean` in briefest duration. `js` at OP returns expected results using `RegExp` constructor and `RegExp.prototype.test()` without including third method `.reduce()`

Comment: I am focusing on the iteration aspect here...yes you can match digits but you still need an iterator or looping function to do the necessary ..isn't it?....my apologies if my approach is a little lack on the performance side but was it worth a try so you now know?

Comment: _"focusing on the iteration aspect here."_ Iteration aspect is not part of requirement. _"my apologies if my approach is a little lack on the performance"_ Performance is focus of Question; see description at original post at _"Requirement: Most efficient method to return Boolean true or false given above parameters , within the least amount of time."_

Comment: So how will you know if you don't try it?You have the tools....DO you expect me to get 71,3307 Dev tools and do a performance test?....SO answers gave you an approach not only a solution......

Comment: If a single number , `35` is passed to `.reduce()` using approach at Answer ; e.g., `[35].reduce(function(a, b) {})`, `res` does not appear to be returned as a `Boolean` value

Comment: Okay..I have added another  solution where values and their corresponding booleans are stores in a list.....thats is about it for me...good nite..:D