# How to convert in Notepad++ using regular expressions?

Tags: regex, notepad++

How to convert `Ctrl+(any letter)` to `«Ctrl+(any letter)»`?

I need like this:

```
Ctrl+T
Ctrl+D
etc.
```

Convert to:

```
«Ctrl+T»
«Ctrl+D»
etc.
```

I tried replacing this `(Ctrl\+.)` with `(Ctrl\+[a-zA-Z])`, but the result is `Ctrl+[a-zA-Z]`.

Comment: You forgot to include your attempt to solve this problem.

Comment: @Scott Hunter I tried replacing this `(Ctrl\+.)` with `(Ctrl\+[a-zA-Z])`, but the result is `Ctrl+[a-zA-Z]`.

Comment: This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/q/21880127/535275

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Find what:

```
(Ctrl\+[a-zA-Z])
```

Replace with:

```
«\1»
```

Make sure Search mode 'Regular expression' is selected.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the full match `$0` in the replacement.

Find what:

```
Ctrl\+[a-zA-Z]
```

Replace with

```
«$0»
```

[image]

**Note** that if you don't want any partial word matches you can use word boundaries `\b`

```
\bCtrl\+[a-zA-Z]\b
```