# Matching numbers patterns using regular expressions (regex)

Tags: regex

Need your kind help in matching some numbers patterns using regex.
I have thousands of 10-digit numbers in the following patterns and need to extract them according to their patterns.

Note - I don't need spaces in between.

**Pattern 1**:
Number: 3527 432 432
Let's consider the above number as
ABCD XYZ XYZ pattern

**Pattern 2**:
Number:
3527 89 89 89
ABCD XY XY XY

**Pattern 3**:
Number:
35 35 35 8745
XY XY XY ABCD

**Pattern 4**:
5432 888 999
ABCD XXX YYY

**Pattern 5**:
5432 8888 99
ABCD XXXX YY

**Pattern 6**
5432 33 44 22
ABCD XX YY ZZ

Any kind of help in any manner is much appreciated.

I am a complete beginner in regex and know basic things.

For patterns like
5432 8888 99

I am using regex like
\d\d\d\d8888\d\d

and then manually find the matching numbers from the list by changing 8888 to other digits like 1111.

Comment: Read about [backreferences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21880127/have-trouble-understanding-capturing-groups-and-back-references). Your first pattern would be something like `\d{4}(\d{3})\1` or `\d{4}\s(\d{3})\s\1` (it's unclear if you need spaces).

Comment: I don't need spaces. And thank you Mark, surely I'll go through given link.

Comment: Do you need to do it 6 separate times, with list of results for every pattern, or in one run with all numbers that match at least one of the patterns put into same list?

Comment: Hello Mark, I need to do it 6 separate times and extract the matching results.

Comment: `\d{4}(\d{3})\1` this is working pretty well. Can you assist me with others as well? I know I am asking for too much but I need this and it will be a learning for me as well. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To check for same symbols, you can use [backreferences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21880127/have-trouble-understanding-capturing-groups-and-back-references).

In short, regex like `(.)\1` will match two same symbols in a row, and `(.)(.)\1\2` will match occurrences like `abab`.

Here expressions for your cases:

1. `\d{4}(\d{3})\1`
2. `\d{4}(\d{2})\1{2}`
3. `(\d{2})\1{2}\d{4}`
4. `\d{4}(\d)\1{2}(\d)\2{2}`
5. `\d{4}(\d)\1{3}(\d)\2`
6. `\d{4}(\d)\1(\d)\2(\d)\3`

Explanation for the firs one:

- `\d{4}` matches any for digits,
- `(\d{3})` matches any three digits, and captures them into group #1,
- `\1` matches exact content of the group #1.

I hope that based on this explanation and general description how backreferences work, others expressions should be pretty clear.

Demo for the first one [here](https://regex101.com/r/sXeoEF/1).

Answer (score -2):

The simplest approach would be to write a pattern for each of the formats.
And then, append them with the `|` character.

Pattern 1 and 4.

```
\d{4} \d{3} \d{3}
```

Pattern 2 and 6.

```
\d{4} \d{2} \d{2} \d{2}
```

Pattern 3.

```
\d{2} \d{2} \d{2} \d{4}
```

Pattern 5.

```
\d{4} \d{4} \d{2}
```

The final pattern would be,

```
\d{4} \d{3} \d{3}|\d{4} \d{2} \d{2} \d{2}|\d{2} \d{2} \d{2} \d{4}|\d{4} \d{4} \d{2}
```

Or, simplified to,

```
\d{4}(?: \d{3}){2}|\d{4}(?: \d{2}){3}|(?:\d{2} ){3}\d{4}|(?:\d{4} ){2}\d{2}
```

You could then use the *[Pattern](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/util/regex/Pattern.html)* and *[Matcher](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/util/regex/Matcher.html)* classes to obtain each value.
Subsequently, use the *[String#replace](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#replace(java.lang.CharSequence,java.lang.CharSequence))* method to remove the spaces.

This presumes they are within a text, and are each delimited by some other character.

I wouldn't rely on this pattern, if the values are sequential and not delimited.

```java
String string = "3527 432 432, 3527 89 89 89, 35 35 35 8745, 5432 888 999, 5432 8888 99, 5432 33 44 22";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\d{4}(?: \\d{3}){2}|\\d{4}(?: \\d{2}){3}|(?:\\d{2} ){3}\\d{4}|(?:\\d{4} ){2}\\d{2}");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);
while (matcher.find())
    System.out.printf("%-20s = %s%n", matcher.group(), matcher.group().replace(" ", ""));
```

Output

```
3527 432 432         = 3527432432
3527 89 89 89        = 3527898989
35 35 35 8745        = 3535358745
5432 888 999         = 5432888999
5432 8888 99         = 5432888899
5432 33 44 22        = 5432334422
```

Here is a link to the *Wikipedia* article on *regular expressions*.
*[Wikipedia – Regular expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression)*.

Comment: Pattern `\d{4} \d{3} \d{3}` will match not only `1234 567 567`, but also `1234 567 890`. Based on description in question, it doesn't look like that's what OP is looking for.

Comment: Hi Reilas, I did not understand `append them with the | character` statement. Correct me if I am wrong but as Mark has said `\d{4} \d{3} \d{3}` is giving me all results which I don't need.

Comment: @rahul, the `|` character is a regex syntax.  Here is the _[Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#POSIX_extended)_.  _'`|`, The choice (also known as alternation or set union) operator matches either the expression before or the expression after the operator. For example, abc|def matches "abc" or "def" ...'_.

Comment: @rahul, now I see, your saying _ABCD_ in terms of each digit.  Sure, I'll re-write it.